# Regex in MongoDB - match until dot

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have string ( which may contains dots ) and I want to find in my collection other records which starts like given string, have dot right after this string and match it until another dot appears.

So for example : string = "Test.Gummy" and I want to look for "Test.Gummy.Yummy", "Test.Gummy.Crummy", etc.

I was trying with:

```
/{string}.*[^.]/ 

/{string}(.*?)\./ 

/{string}\.*[^.]/ 

/{string}\.(.*?)\./
```

but that doesn't work..

Answer (score 1):

Your regex would be,

```
/{string}\.[^\.]*/
```

**Explanation:**

- `\.` Matches a literal dot.
- `[^\.]*` Matches any characters not of dot zero or more times.

Comment: It still finds strings like "Test.Gummy.Yummy.Something.Else".

Comment: still the same :/ I'm not sure whether mongo regex are a little different?

Comment: Mongodb uses PCRE library for regex so the above command should work. I think you made a mistake in your code.Does the string variable expands correctly. OH, i forget that. Other languages won't support variables in regexes(`//`). You need to include the regex within double quotes.

Comment: I'm using robomongo to test it. It's easy mongo client for linux. I've just wrote { 'field' : { $regex : 'exemplary_expression' } } and it shows me results.